# Diff between gnome gnome and installing gnome desktop environment?

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

i installed gnome desktop over normal ubuntu 15.04 and using it but there is a gnome desktop os version available ,does the gnome ubuntu contains only the desktop enviroment that i installed from USC or it has more to it

Answer (score 0):

If you start from a common base-point (`ubuntu-minimal`, or `ubuntu-standard`), then installing `*-desktop` package will provide you the same effect as installing the corresponding Ubuntu flavour directly. These packages are called *metapackages*. The [community wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages#Ubuntu_System_Metapackages) has this to say:

> One of the handy features of apt (the packaging system used by Ubuntu)
>   is the use of metapackages. These packages do not contain actual
>   software, they simply depend on other packages to be installed. This
>   setup allows entire sets of software to be installed by selecting only
>   the appropriate metapackage. For example, an Ubuntu user can install
>   the Kubuntu environment (KDE and all its associated programs) by
>   selecting "kubuntu-desktop."
>
> ...
>
> ### Ubuntu System Metapackages
>
> 1. **edubuntu-desktop**: This package depends on all of the packages in the edubuntu desktop system
> 2. **edubuntu-server**: This package depends on all of the packages in the edubuntu server system
> 3. **kubuntu-desktop**: Similar to ubuntu-desktop, but with KDE and related software instead of Gnome
> 4. **ubuntu-desktop**: In addition to ubuntu-minimal and ubuntu-standard, this package depends on all of the packages in the
>      Ubuntu desktop system. It installs a desktop environment (GNOME) and
>      lots of software for home and office use.
> 5. **ubuntu-minimal**: This package depends on all of the packages in the Ubuntu minimal system, that is a functional command-line system
>      with the following capabilities: Boot, Detect hardware, Connect to a
>      network, Install packages, and Perform basic diagnostics. It is also
>      used to help ensure proper upgrades, so it is recommended that it not
>      be removed.
> 6. **ubuntu-restricted-extras**: Introduced in Feisty, this package depends on some commonly used packages in the Ubuntu multiverse
>      repository. It installs support for java, flash, microsoft truetype
>      fonts, and many multimedia codecs.
> 7. **ubuntu-standard**: In addition to ubuntu-minimal, this package depends on all of the packages in the Ubuntu standard system. This set
>      of packages provides a comfortable command-line Unix-like environment.
> 8. **xubuntu-desktop**: The XFCE desktop environment, and all the software distributed with Xubuntu
> 9. **lubuntu-desktop**: The LXDE desktop environment, and all the software distributed with Lubuntu

The page hasn't been updated in a while, so Ubuntu GNOME isn't mentioned. However, as can be seen from the descriptions of the other packages, they al include all the software that the corresponding flavour provides.

For Ubuntu GNOME, this includes the Ubuntu Software Centre, which is a recommended package (and by default, recommended packages are installed too).